# Chart Controls acting weird

Tags: c#

I Have two different chart controls, one that works perfectly fine and it gets erased and filled again with array plots everytime I press a certain button.

The second one should have been just as easy, I have it tied to another button that when pressed should plot some other data. For some reason, using the same code (adapted for this case nonetheless) it says that the series that I defined in the second chart doesn't exist. Ok, I thought, maybe if I add that series to my first chart.

That worked, but I don't see why, I never once referenced either of the charts' name.

Anyawys, this is the code, it really beats me:

```
private void Calc_Atunci_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
[...] some code [...]

        Chart_Model.Series["C"].Points.Clear();
        Chart_Model.Series["I"].Points.Clear();

            for (j = 0; j <i; j++)
            {
                Chart_Model.Series["C"].Points.Add(Cazuri_Interval[j]);
                Chart_Model.Series["I"].Points.Add(Incidenta_Interval[j]);
            }
```

And it says that there's no such thing as a 'C' series. Although I added it.

This is the code for the other chart that works, but I really need two charts:

```
 private void Model_Matematic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chart_Model.Series["S"].Points.Clear();
            Chart_Model.Series["I"].Points.Clear();
            Chart_Model.Series["R"].Points.Clear();
            Chart_Model.Series["D"].Points.Clear();
            Chart_Model.Series["E"].Points.Clear();

[...] some code [...]

                        Chart_Model.Series["S"].Points.Add(SIRD_Model.S_Array[i]);
                        Chart_Model.Series["I"].Points.Add(SIRD_Model.I_Array[i]); 
                        Chart_Model.Series["R"].Points.Add(SIRD_Model.R_Array[i]);
                        Chart_Model.Series["D"].Points.Add(SIRD_Model.D_Array[i]);
[...] some more code [...]
}
```

This is literally all the things that I used for the charts and it drives me cray cray, one works, one doesn't. Help a brother out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you doubt that you never added the "C" series??

Comment: I added the C series in the second chart but it doesn't recognize it

Comment: Doubtful. Does it show in the designer? (Or if you add in code: Show the code and use the debugger to see what series are really there..!)